# Simple open source DHT implementation in Java for learning purposes

Tags: java, dht

I'm looking for recommendations for a simple open source implementation of a **Distributed Hash Table** in Java to play around with. No fancy features, just for learning purposes, no production functionality needed. It should be simple to set up (e.g. 1 physical machine with n-JVMs) and well documented preferably with some examples, tutorials or starting guides.

Research yields these candidates: [FreePastry](http://www.freepastry.org/) and [OpenChord](http://open-chord.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not fully convinced they meet my criteria simplicity-wise.

Have you got any experience with these or other implementations? Recommendations?

Thanks & adios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [JDHT](https://web.archive.org/web/20150604162150/http://dks.sics.se/jdht/) will fit the bill. I haven't checked it out myself, but it's written at a university, sometimes that means it's simple and used for teaching. :-)

Comment: Broken link to JDHT. I googled around a bit to try and find if it moved, but its not easy to find. Maybe project is dead. At leasts its 'footprint' on the internet seems to indicate so.

Answer (score 11):

There is [TomP2P](https://github.com/tomp2p/TomP2P) on Github.

Comment: Looks best to me as of 2015: active development and lots of commiters on github, more than 50 forks, android support.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working on [an implementation of Kademlia](https://github.com/JoshuaKissoon/Kademlia) lately. It's very simple to setup and use and it's well documented. There are several tests written that demonstrate the different functionality as well as a starting guide in the Readme.md file itself.

Comment: I forked your repo just now but I can't seem to find your test sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [openkad](http://code.google.com/p/openkad/)

Comment: Looks dead. The download link takes you to an empty folder on google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I started with free pastry..I've had a great experience with it. It was very simple to set up and run a ring of nodes. I've been mainly using PAST (File storage) and its been quite easy to get running. I'd suggest having a look at the PAST tutorial here. https://trac.freepastry.org/wiki/tut_past

The code is over simplified in my opinion but you say that is all you need so I guess thats ok.