# P2P java file transfer

Tags: java, file-upload, download, p2p

First off, I am VERY new to Java, but wanted to know if it was possible. I could not find any tutorials or explanation online:

Is it possible to send/receive files not through a server, but P2P.
I want a file, when selected, to be sent to another PC running the client.
What is the best method of doing this? Is there something I have missed?

(P.s. My first stackoverflow question, please be nice :D)

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But generally firewalls make it difficult/impossible to do so, especially if either client is behind a NAT gateway.

Comment: Search here on SO for P2P + Java. There are a lot of questions and answers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [JXTA](http://java.net/projects/jxta) a try, it should satisfy all your needs.

Or try a DHT implementation for the P2P part and implement the file transfer either over the DHT or just the sesssion initiation by DHT and some other kind of direct file transfer.

- [openkad](http://code.google.com/p/openkad/)
- [JDHT](http://dks.sics.se/jdht/)

(DHT selection taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989029/simple-open-source-dht-implementation-in-java-for-learning-purposes/5989063#5989063))

Comment: Thank you for the help :)
Although I find the 170 page guide very daunting, I will definitely be having a look at JXTA. Do you have any particular resources/tutorials that helped you start off?(Link for any others out there: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2005/jw-0509-jxta.html?page=1)

Comment: This one looks good, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-jxta/ but I have no particular HowTos i would recommend, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/november/15.html

Every Peer in a P2P-system will have both roles (receiver AND sender that is each peer is server AND client at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. Check the [Free Pastry implementation](http://www.freepastry.org/)

Answer (score 0):

JXTA are a little complex to someone new in Java and it has some limitations with scalability and perfomance of his communications layers. Another option is [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), if a pure P2P is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Pastry provides a DHT. Its done Java and very easy to use. Its storage system is known as PAST and a tutorial can be found here : https://trac.freepastry.org/wiki/tut_past

I've had a great experience working with it.